# How to group element by minute in x axis user Rickshaw?

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I have array:

```
var array = [];
var object1 = {};
object1.x = 1458083620;
object1.y = 5;
array.push(object1);

var object2 = {};
object2.x = 1458083690;
object2.y = 4;
array.push(object2);
```

And I want to display this array:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
            element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
            renderer: 'scatterplot',
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            series: [{
                data: array,
                color: 'steelblue',
                name: 'count'
            }]

});

var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
            graph: graph,
            orientation: 'left',
            tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
            element: document.getElementById('y_axis')
});

graph.render();

var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
            graph: graph
} );
```

But at screen I see, that 2 elements (`object1` and `object2`) at the same line. 
[image]

How to group elements by hour / minute / second ?

Note: HTML-code

```
<div id="chart_container">
    <div id="y_axis"></div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are assigning the x and y properties to your objects could be the problem.

You could try assigning the object properties like the following example.

Javascript:

```
//array to hold objects
var array = [];

//object1 with its properties
var object1 = {
    "x":1458083620,
    "y":5
};

//add object1 to the array
array.push(object1);


//object2 with its properties
var object2 = {

"x":1458083690,
"y":4

};

//add object2 to the array
array.push(object2);
```